# Почему при создании вопроса справа появляется текст на английском языке, хотя сайт на русском языке?

Tags: дефект, локализация, регистрация

Почему при создании вопроса справа появляется текст на английском языке, хотя сайт на русском языке? Мета требует регистрации, хотя написано no registration required.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не могу сделать тревогу на собственном вопросе почему-то, чтобы привлечь внимание модератора о переносе на meta

Comment: Наверное, из-за того что регистрация нужна хотя опять же нигде не сказано про это

Comment: Нет, это не дубликат вопроса 2017 года, это свеженький баг от недавнего обновления очередей проверок.

Comment: Почему тогда у того вопроса нет метки [meta-tag:статус-завершено]?

Comment: @AK еще какой дубликат! Вообще один в один.